# LongListSelector Data Binding Issue

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, longlistselector

I am a beginner in windows Windows phone programming.
i am trying to implement LongListSelector to display group by products.

here are my classes :

```
public class ProductMaster {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProductSubMaster> Models { get; set; }
}


public class ProductSubMaster
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ProductSubMasterProperty modelProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSubMasterProperty{
    public string ProNo { get; set; }
    public Uri ProImage { get; set; }

}
```

and my xaml :

```
 <phone:LongListSelector
                    x:Name="ProductList"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding  objProduct}"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    LayoutMode="List"
                    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                    HideEmptyGroups ="False">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5">
                                <Border Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="500" 
                                        Height="62" Margin="0,0,18,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=[0].Name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" Padding="10" 
                                                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image x:Name="searchimg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Source="{Binding Path=Models.modelProperty.ProImage}" Height="100" Width="100" ></Image>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ProductName"  Margin="20,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Models.Name}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                                <Image x:Name="bookmarkimg"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Source="/Assets/Media/star.png" Height="40" Width="30" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
```

i am facing the issue for binding ItemTemplate

Please help me out

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have added listbox in itemtemplate solved my issue

here is my updated code

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBox x:Name="LstFeaturesData" Visibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Models}" Margin="0,0">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image x:Name="searchimg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Source="{Binding Path=modelProperty.ProImage}" Height="100" Width="100" ></Image>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="ProductName"  Margin="20,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                                                <Image x:Name="bookmarkimg"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Source="/Assets/Media/star.png" Height="40" Width="30" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: your salutation may cause rendering problems

Comment: like? @SwiftSharp